# In HTML5 how do you make spefic video players pop up as a result of dropping and dragging spefic images into a div?

Tags: javascript, html, css, drag-and-drop, html5-video

I am able to drop and drag images into a div. I have 2 images. My problem is I want when Image 1 "carrots.jpg" is dragged and dropped into the div for a video to play lets say "video 1" and when Image 2 "pepper.png" is dragged and dropped into the div for "video 2" to play. I would like the videos to show up in pop-up windows. How do I do this? Here is some of my code to display how I'm doing the drop and drag event.

```
#div1 {width:20%;height:20%;
position:absolute;
left:50%;
top:50%;
margin-right: -50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
z-index:-1;

}
#drag2{width:20%; height:20%; position:absolute;

left:50%;
top:50%;
margin-right: -50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
z-index:-2;

    }
#drag1{ width:10%; height:10%;
position:absolute;
top:50%;
left:20%;
margin-right: -20%;
transform: translate(-20%, -25%);
z-index:-3;
    }

#drag3{ width:10%; height:10%;
position:absolute;
top:70%;
left:30%;
margin-right: -30%;
transform: translate(-30%, -70%);
z-index:-3;
    }   

</style>


<script>
function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
    ev.target.removeChild(document.getElementById(data));

}
</script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>


<img id="drag2" src="Pot.jpg" draggable="false"
ondragstart="drag(event)" >



<img id="drag1" src="carrots.jpg" draggable="true"
ondragstart="drag(event)" >

<img id="drag3" src="pepper.png" draggable="true"
ondragstart="drag(event)" >


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to assume that by "show up in pop-up windows", you mean "pop up in the same window", because actual pop-ups are annoying, everyone hates them, and browsers often block them.

You can put the videos in your HTML document from the start, but hidden, using "display = none" in CSS. In your `drop(ev)` function, you then show one of the videos with:

```
if (data == 'drag1')
  var video = document.getElementById('video1');
else
  video = document.getElementById('video2');
video.style.display = 'block';
video.play();
```

or, instead of the `if` statement, you can just transform the ID of the drag source into the ID of the video, if you number them the same:

```
var video = document.getElementById('video' + data.slice(-1))
```

Or you might have the video wrapped in an absolutely-positioned div or something to provide a frame around it, in which case the frame would be the element with  "display = none".

Comment: Hi, thank you that worked and helped alot, I was wondering if you could help me with the latter part of my question which is how do I make 1 image  play video and another image play a different video I've been playing around with things and having trouble figuring this out

Comment: Sorry, I thought you had solved that already. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Thank you again worked perfect, and sorry im really new to making websites